# Calculated field from multiple tables

Tags: database, ms-access, field, calculated-field

I am currently using visual studio and microsoft access. Is there any way to have a calculated field take from fields that are not in the same table as the calculated field?

Comment: How would you pick the value you need from the second table?

Comment: That is what I am asking. When making an expression, is it possible to refer to a field on a different table?

Comment: Yes, perhaps you should be making a View though. You need to be able to relate the row of data in your table with the calculated column to your other table somehow. That "somehow" is up to you because you know the relationship be tween the tables.